# what kind of relation will exist between a member and a P2P network classes in a class diagram?

Tags: uml

I have a member class which stores the IP, and ports used on that member.
Another class P2P stores a list of all the members currently in the network and provides join,leave functionality. What kind of relationship will exist between them in  a class diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The P2P list 'has a' member, use [Aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Aggregation) relation

> a variant of the "has a" association relationship; aggregation is more specific than association. It is an association that represents a part-whole or part-of relationship. As a type of association, an aggregation can be named and have the same adornments that an association can. However, an aggregation may not involve more than two classes.
>
> Aggregation can occur when a class is a collection or container of other classes, but where the contained classes do not have a strong *life cycle dependency* on the container — essentially, if the container is destroyed, its contents are not.
>
> In UML, it is graphically represented as a *hollow* diamond shape on the containing class end of the tree with a single line that connects the contained class to the containing class.The aggregate is semantically an extended object that is treated as a unit in many operations,although physically it is made of several lesser objects...
>
> [image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/KP-UML-Aggregation-20060420.svg/300px-KP-UML-Aggregation-20060420.svg.png]